# All URLs are redirected to index.php

Tags: php, symphony-cms

I have setup a Symphony framework on my localhost using [this](https://www.getsymphony.com/learn/tutorials/beginners/) tutorial. I am using the PHP default server and MySQL.
The frontend URL is working fine but when I go to the admin URL (`http://localhost:8000/symdemo/admin`), then my CSS URL is also redirected to the admin page meaning I am not getting CSS code into the response.

The reason as that the default PHP server does not have a URL-rewriting module and `index.php` is also adding to the CSS path.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft yes I know its localhost url, I just provide it for reference only. Actually I found the reason, because default php server has not the feature of url rewrite module thats why this error is coming because index.php is adding in css path also

Comment: that is not accessible to browser.

Comment: If you have any solution for url rewrite in default php server which work in symphony setup then please help me

Comment: I just found what is the problem, still I am searching for solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you'll find that using a webserver that supports rewrites is quicker than trying to replicate the necessary rewrites in PHP. [Rewrites are listed as a requirement in Symphony CMS's readme](https://github.com/symphonycms/symphony-2#server-requirements), and last time I checked Symphony was still dependent on webserver rewrites for some of its routing/files.

You can, of course, use Apache. If you'd like to use a lighter and cleaner webserver that's easy to configure, I recommend [Hiawatha](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/), which has a Symphony [URL toolkit/rewrite rule set](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/howto/url_rewrite_rules) available.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to use url rewrite into default php server that support by Symphony